# Determining if $0$ is part of this set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a set of rational numbers that is closed under addition and multiplication, and having the property that for every rational number $r$ exactly one the following three statements is true: $r\in S$, $-r\in S$, $r=0$.

There are a couple of questions I have to prove but I am having trouble with the first one:

Prove that $0$ does not belong to $S$. I think I am confused by the last statement where it says $r$ is exactly one of the following three statements part since it seems to say it is okay for $r=0$ but that seems like it violates $r\in S$ and $-r \in S$ since $0 = -0$. Or is there some other thing I am missing completely? Thank you for any help in this!

Comment: If $0 \in S$, the three statements are true for $r=0$!!

Comment: Taking $r=0$ in your condition gives you that $0 \not\in S$.

Comment: Okay cool, while you are here can I ask what the notation of $-r \in S$ means, it just seems odd to include a negative sign in the beginning of a variable. Does that mean if $r = -\frac{1}{2}$ then $-r = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, of course @InsigMath...and for zero you have that $\;0=-0=+0\;$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Exactly* here signifies "one and only one" of the three statements is true for each element in $S$.

$0\notin S$ because if it were an element of $S$, all statements are true, simultaneously, and so it violates the "one and only one" restriction.

To  prove $0 \notin S$, you can start by assuming (for the sake of contradiction), that $0  \in S.$ Then show that this assumption leads to a contradiction, allowing you to conclude: therefore, $r\notin S$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $0 \in S$ (our hypothesis).

Then $0 \in S$ and $-0 \in S$.

So, at least two (and not exactly one) of the statements is true.

So, $0 \notin S$.

Because our hypothesis leads to a contradiction, the hypothesis cannot be true.